# Get the CERT_RDN information from the certificate object

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm opening the certificate store using the "CertOpenStore" API and get the certificates using the "CertEnumCertificatesInStore" API.
The CERT_CONTEXT data returned by the API gives the issuer name in CERT_NAME_BLOB type. 
How to get the CERT_RDN or CERT_NAME_INFO from the certificate.?
My requirement is to get the issuer name attributes (O, OU, etc.). I do not want to parse the string returned by the CertNameToStr API.

Comment: The best way IMHO is to use an ASN.1 parser. Load raw certificate data (DER encoded) and find subject or issuer by following the structure of X509 certificate as defined by [RFC5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above comment is correct, you do need to decode the ASN.1 encoded data in the `CERT_NAME_BLOB`. However, the CryptoAPI has a function to do this for you - `CryptDecodeObject`.

If you have a `PCCERT_CONTEXT` handle `pCertContext`, you can decode it to a `CERT_NAME_INFO` structure as follows:

```
BOOL success = CryptDecodeObject(
    X509_ASN_ENCODING,
    X509_NAME,
    pCertContext->pCertInfo->Issuer.pbData,
    pCertContext->pCertInfo->Issuer.cbData,
    0,
    NULL,
    &dwNameInfoSize);

// (check that CryptDecodeObject succeeded)    

PCERT_NAME_INFO pCertNameInfo = (PCERT_NAME_INFO) malloc(dwNameInfoSize);

// (check that malloc succeeded)

CryptDecodeObject(
    X509_ASN_ENCODING,
    X509_NAME,
    pCertContext->pCertInfo->Issuer.pbData,
    pCertContext->pCertInfo->Issuer.cbData,
    0,
    pCertNameInfo,
    &dwNameInfoSize);
```

Now you can loop through the different components of the RDN like this:

```
for (DWORD i = 0; i < pCertNameInfo->cRDN; i++)
{
    for (DWORD j = 0; j < pCertNameInfo->rgRDN[i].cRDNAttr; j++)
    {
        CERT_RDN_ATTR &rdnAttribute = pCertNameInfo->rgRDN[i].rgRDNAttr[j];

        //
        // Do stuff with the RDN attribute
        //
    }
}
```

With each iteration, `rdnAttribute` will be set to a different component of the issuer name like you want.

Finally, free the memory when you're done:

```
free(pCertNameInfo);
```